# Lock mouse position when dragging element with jQuery UI sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I use jQuery UI sortable plugin to let users reorder divs with in a container.

In the plugin's settings i set `axis:"y"` to constrain the dragging movement to a vertical movement only.

When the user drags the `div` the mouse position is staying the same (relative to the dragged `div`) vertically but horizontally the mouse moves freely and (to my opinion) it gives a less "firm" / "stable" ui experience and i want the mouse to stay on the same position (relative to the `div`) while dragging.

Any ideas how to do that?

[Demo](https://codepen.io/bentalgad/pen/zpZLGp)

Note: when the sorting isn't constrain to to a vertical movement only the mouse is locked to the first position natively.

Answer (score 0):

controlling mouse position with JS is tough to do and not advisable. Still, if you want to do this you should take a look at the Pointer Lock API, although I am not sure it will accomplish what you're looking for.

Kind regards,